# Rmarkdown, shiny app : pdf edition fail with kable_styling option

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny, kableextra

I am currently trying to generate and export a pdf file from a shiny app.
I generate a table by using kable (it works).

When I add kable_styling options to my table (kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down"))), it cannot generate my pdf file with this error : 
Error : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Note : I have check my pandoc version is to date.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot

here is my input.rmd

````
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document

---

```{r echo=T}
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

kable(cbind(dt,dt, dt, dt, dt), "markdown") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down"))

kable(dt, format = "latex", booktabs = T, caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("table footnote"))

test3<-kable(dt, "markdown") 
  kable_styling(test3, font_size=14)
```



Tableau2
`r test3`
````

and the shiny app :

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)

shinyApp(
 ui = fluidPage(
basicPage(

  downloadButton('report'))

  ),
server = function(input, output) {
output$report = downloadHandler(
  filename = 'myreport.pdf',
  content = function(file) {
    out = render('input.Rmd', clean = TRUE, encoding='utf-8')
    file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
  },

  contentType = 'application/pdf'
)
 }
)
```

Comment: Works fine for me ...

Comment: try to upgrade your rmarkdown version

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have the last version of Rmarkdown. I have the error message in another more complex shiny app. Maybe it is due to the fail of scaling the table ( kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down")) don't work in my pdf (## Currently generic markdown table using pandoc is not supported).